# How can I delete VBA objects in a Recovered Workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I was working with VBA when Excel crashed.

I recovered the workbook but instead of having named sheets, it created a Workbook? object for each sheet.

[image]

I cannot delete these objects with the GUI, and which means I also cannot change the sheet names back.

I get an error:

> Invalid Property Value

I assume this is because of the object. (Note: I can change the sheet name to something else.)

Comment: Did you try creating new workbook and copy-pasting sheets from an old workbook into a new one?

Comment: Try to copy and paste the sheets to a new workbook hopefully you solve this.

Comment: You can probably modify the list in workbook.xml after unzipping the file, but that might make it worse

Comment: Unzipping worked for fixing the name property, but i still have to figure out where the workbook objects are stored.(to delete all these extra ones)

I exported all my vba modules, so I can try to copy paste the sheets (and this is probably the cleaner method), but it's always cool to explore XML

Comment: @Slai ---Note: I had to Edit <sheetPr codename=""/> in each sheets XML

Comment: that's actually pretty cool, because I never thought a workbook can contain more than one workbook object :] There are few more .xml files that contain the relations between the objects/sheets, but I am not sure what's stored in vbaProject.bin. The recovery window probably showed the affected .xml files if you have access to it.

Comment: Why not just to disable the macro in the trust center by opening a new workbook and the open the recovered wb and rename the sheet as wanted ?